# Sonar, S128: Switch cases should end with an unconditional "break" statement VS continue

Tags: java, sonarqube

The rule squid:128 seems to exist to prevent fall-through  in switch case unless explicitly stated. It seems a reasonable rule, as forgetting a break is a common mistake.

However fall-through are perfectly valid when wanted.

The Documentation of this rule states that the only way to achieve a fall-through is to use continue

```
   case 4:                                // Use of continue statement
   continue;
```

I have also checked the source code of SwitchCaseWithoutBreakCheck are the implementation really check for "continue" statement

```
  @Override
  public void visitContinueStatement(ContinueStatementTree tree) {
    super.visitContinueStatement(tree);
    markSwitchCasesAsCompliant();
  }
```

However, the Java language does not support continue in switch/case. Nor the online documentation nor ./java-checks/src/test/files/checks/SwitchCaseWithoutBreakCheck.java are valid Java programs.

Am I missing something or is this rule fully broken and prevent using fall-through ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are totally right in saying that the description here is wrong and then you actually have no way to do not trigger the rule if you want to actually use fallthrough (and thus you might want either to mark issue as false positive in this case or deactivate the rule alltogether)

calling the rule "broken" is an opinion so I won't argue on that ;)

Nevertheless, a ticket has been created to handle the issue : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1169

Comment: Thanks for creating the ticket. I agree that allowing or forbidding fallthrough is subjective. However, if the aim of  S128 is to forbid fallthrough I believe that the documentation should state it more clearly. If not, it would be great to be able explicitly state that a given fallthrough is intended (IIRC it was possible to use a specific trailing comment at some point). Both disabling the rule and marking the issue as false positive fail at making the fallthrough explicit for the reader. [Note: I had prefer to directly contribute on Jira but it seems not possible to create an account]

Comment: So, and how **can** we achieve a desired `/* FALLTHROUGH */` (lint for C syntax)?